# Error with PublishSymbols Task in Azure DevOps - "RequestSealedException: Request is sealed. Only expirationDate may be modified."

Tags: azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml, debug-symbols

I am encountering an issue with the PublishSymbols task in my Azure DevOps pipeline. The exact error message I receive is as follows:

```
[Symbol App] Microsoft.VisualStudio.Services.Symbol.WebApi.RequestSealedException: Request ... is sealed. Only expirationDate may be modified.
```

The section of my pipeline configuration concerning the PublishSymbols task is as follows:

```
# Publish symbols for Windows builds
- task: PublishSymbols@2
  system.debug: true
  displayName: 'Publish symbols'
  inputs:
    SymbolsFolder: '$(Build.SourcesDirectory)/webrtc/native/src/out'
    SearchPattern: '**/webrtc.pdb'
    SymbolServerType: TeamServices
    SymbolsVersion: '$(WebrtcVersion)'
    SymbolsArtifactName: 'Symbols_WebRTC_$(BuildPlatform)_$(BuildSystem)'
  condition: and(eq(variables['BuildConfiguration'], 'Release'), in(variables['BuildSystem'], 'Windows'))
```

The error message implies that a request is sealed. However, I'm not sure what this means or how to resolve it.

Answer (score 2):

It seems it's a bug in [PublishSymbols@2 task](https://github.com/microsoft/azure-pipelines-tasks/issues/18548). There are two workarounds for that:

1.Simply remove the **SymbolsArtifactName** field. Or

2.Make **SymbolsArtifactName** unique by appending **_$(Build.BuildNumber)** to its value.

```
  SymbolsArtifactName: 'Symbols_WebRTC_$(BuildPlatform)_$(BuildSystem)_$(Build.BuildNumber)'
```